# Existe un análogo de "as of (yesterday)" en español?

Tags: traducción, tiempo

En inglés, la construcción "as of" es más o menos equivalente a "desde" o "a partir de", pero los usos no coinciden exactamente. En particular, frases como

> The website was down as of last Monday

suelen indicar que el suceso ("the website was down") definitivamente ocurre a partir del momento especificado ("last Monday"), pero no descartan la posibilidad de que hubiera empezado antes.

Existe una frase equivalente, con esa propiedad, en español?

Answer (score 8):

Se podría decir:

> La página ya estaba caída el lunes.
>
> La página ya estaba caída por lo menos desde el lunes.

Comment: +1 ... también puedes prescindir del "ya"

Comment: @belisarius I upvoted your [breathing avatar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/animating-mathematica-se-logo/13170#13170), nice job on mathematica

Answer (score 4):

Se podría decir:

> La página web estaba caída a día de ayer
>
> La página web no estaba disponible a día de ayer

Answer (score 1):

> ... no después del lunes.

diría yo.